# How to load the assets of my website without "403 forbidden"

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm having a little problem. I want to redirect people to a maintenance site except me. To do this, I put everything in a .htaccess file and it works.

However, when I load my website, I see it appear in the files I try to load "403 Forbidden". In fact, when I try to access them in the form: example.com/css/main.css appears 403 Forbidden.

I've tried several things, because my idea is to load the website only to me to make the changes.

Then I leave my .htaccess file (my application is in Laravel):

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ip 172.xx.xx.xxx
</RequireAny>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|assets)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^assets/.*
RewriteRule .? - [L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Without your .htaccess, you also get a 403, correct? Then Laravel is the one preventing you from accessing your website.

Comment: No, without my .htaccess files load correctly @AlexisWilke

Comment: did you create symbolic link ?  `php artisan storage:link` ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a built-in maintenance mode feature that allows you to whitelist your IP address.  This will prevent anyone but you from accessing the site, as others will see a maintenance page (503 response).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#maintenance-mode

```php
// enable maintenance mode
php artisan down --allow=172.xx.xx.xxx

// make the application live again
php artisan up
```

In addition, you can extend the default maintenance mode middleware `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode` for more control, such as specific route exclusions.